# Azure AD send access token to Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I'm writing a two part web application, a frontend single page application written in JavaScript using msal.js and a backend Web API written in C# ASP.Net Core 2.2. I've integrated login through msal.js on the frontend. I'm sending the Access Token to the Web API as a Bearer token.

I'd like to know how to validate the token to only give access to signed in users. I'd also like to know whether using an access token is the right way forward as I'd have to request a new one each time, even though I won't be using it to request Microsoft's APIs, it will only be used to access internal data.

Here's the wanted flow:
[image: Image of wanted flow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the token using standard ASP.NET Core JWT authentication.
I have a while article on the subject: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-AD-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1.

You'll need to configure the authentication with something like this

```
services
            .AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Both App ID URI and client id are valid audiences in the access token
                    ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                    {
                        Configuration["Authentication:AppIdUri"],
                        Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]
                    }
                };
            });
```

You'll also want to check that the token contains at least one valid scope/permission.

You don't need to get a new token for each call, MSAL.js handles renewal when needed for you. It just returns it from cache if it is still valid.

Comment: Thanks it worked, however, I realised later that I'm in need of a different approach as the Web API will have multiple web apps linked to it. Which will result in multiple client ids, tenant ids, etc... accessing the same Web API. This wouldn't be an issue if the client wasn't in need of using a secret key, but I can't do that as my app is a single page application which will be running on a web server like nginx or apache.

Comment: Okay, why would your API have multiple ids? You can register the API as an app in AAD and have client apps require permissions to it. Then if you need to support more than one tenant, you can make the API multi-tenant, and consent it into each tenant.

Comment: My API wouldn't have multiple ids, the different web apps would, as they'll be completing different tasks and have different domains assigned to them. So each of the web apps would be registered as their own app in AAD as well as the API.

Comment: You shouldn't need to register your API more than once, unless you really want to have strong separation between them. There are ways to implement that too, but it would involve quite a lot of custom work. Usually we use the same API registration and all the client apps require access to that.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me, I've made a new issue as this is out of the scope of the original issue and I've added some clarifications. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57691531/azure-ad-connect-multiple-apps-to-single-web-api

Comment: Hey I want to do the same with MVC 5 (non .net core). I'm struggling a way to validate the Azure AD token created with my frontend from backend MVC. Any guide will be highly appreciated :)