# Azure AD connect multiple apps to single Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Web API written using asp.net core. This API will be used to communicate with several other services registered in AAD, which all could be made using different technologies like an MVC application written in asp.net core or a single page application written in Vue.JS. The latter is causing me issues as the SPA won't be run by an application web server and rather something like nginx or apache and therefor won't be able to use a client secret.

I have added API permissions for my API to my apps.

How would I achieve this? I'm currently sending an access token using the `Authorization: Bearer access_token` header from the client app to the API, but since the client app and the API aren't the same app in the AAD, it's causing issues.

Here's the flow I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Image describing wanted flow[1]]

All of the requested apps require you to login to the AAD and when requesting data from the API, they'll send the JWT token, which then should validate the token before returning the requested resource back to the client application.

Comment: If you want to know how to access web api projected by Azure AD, please refer to the sample(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/1.%20Desktop%20app%20calls%20Web%20API).

Comment: @test123 That's not the issue here, I can already do this. The issue comes from connecting multiple applications to a single Web API, which wouldn't be an issue either if only all of the applications were asp.net MVC apps or if all of the apps has a web server connected to the them, but I've got an SPA, which is static files.

Comment: Is that you want to how the SAP can access the API?

Comment: @test123 Yes, I know how to do that though. The issue comes when I want the SPA to connect to the API while other applications (like other SPAs) registered as different AAD apps try to connect to the same API.

Comment: Regarding the SPA, you can use the oauth2 implicit grant flow to access web api. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Comment: @test123 That is what I've already got working, however, due to the way that SPAs differ from the regular flow, this approach will only allow me to connect apps that use the same AAD keys as the Web API, which I can't do as I'll be connecting several different apps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198595/discussion-between-tarkan-and-test123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand something . You can register your each client as independent application in Azure AD , and assign access permission for your web api .

> The latter is causing me issues as the SPA won't be run by an application web server and rather something like nginx or apache and therefor won't be able to use a client secret.

SPA application use  [Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) , so that it doesn't need the client secret when acquiring token .SPA could be independent app , you should provide client id when making authentication with AAD. After getting access token , you could create http request with `Authorization: Bearer access_token`header for accessing your web api .

Each client(web/spa/native) will acquire access token for accessing web api . On web api side , you just need to validate the token .Validate the claims(issuer,audience) and signature .

Comment: You're right and using the examples from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof I managed to get everything working perfectly. Thank you.